# Make Ubuntu 16.04 server ask for a password when logged in

Tags: 16.04, server, amazon-ec2, aws

I have an ec2 instance created with AWS. I want to make it protected by prompting a password whenever a user log in.

Comment: Why? Because that is NOT how instances work: you do NOT login through the normal login, you use ssh or something similar. You can only connect to an instance from locations you approve; how you approve this is not done by setting a password. I would advice you to start using private/public keys. That way you can force using a user and password from the program you connect with.

Comment: i am new to this. can you guide me on how to do it. i use a .pem file to access the instance. but i want only one user to use it, no matter who ever has the key.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-ec2-keypairs.html  and "no matter who ever has the key" is never ever ever going to be possible. Having the key = access. You can envoke a new key so the old one in invalid but having it means access.  Otherwise how is your instance going to know it is you. We use encrypted USB sticks to hold the keys and those USB sticks can only be inserted into 1 notebook. And for all other systems the USB requires a password to open.  And even then: if someone gets hold of the private key and the IP for the instance we are screwed.

Answer (score 1):

AWS Linux system comes with by default key-based authentication,
if you prefer only password-based authentication, here are the steps

1. login using the key file,

`ssh ubuntu@ip_address`

2. change the password for the current user,

`sudo passwd ubuntu`

set the new password.

then change the ssd_config file to allow password-based authentication.

in file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

replace PasswordAuthentication to yes

save and exit.

now I strictly suggest you exit the system and try password-based method before you log out since if you log out messing up the sshd_config file, it is difficult to revert it.

try logging in with a password, and if it works.

set PubkeyAuthentication to no, to disable key based authentication.